# JOOQ use Record7 to encapsulate fields from different tables

Tags: java, jooq

I'm using JOOQ to retrieve records from 2 tables, i created custom object `NearByPlace`of returned columns, i read about `Record7`and see that it's much better to use it rather than creating new object as below, i tried it but it failed in compilation saying that can't convert from `Org.JOOQ.Record7` to record of below aliases, any idea of how to do that?

```
public List<NearByPlace> getNearBy(NearByRequestWrapper wrapper) {

return db().select(
    PLACE.NAME.as("placeName"),
    PLACE.TYPE.as("placeType"),
    PLACE.LAT.as("lat"),
    PLACE.LON.as("lon"),
    EVENT.NAME.as("eventName"),
    DSL.field("earth_distance(ll_to_earth(" + wrapper.lat() + "," + wrapper.lon() + "),ll_to_earth(place.lat, place.lon))* 0.000621371192").as("distanceToReach"),
    DSL.field(EVENT.TYPE).as("eventType"))
    .from(PLACE)
    .leftJoin(EVENT)
    .on(PLACE.ID.eq(EVENT.LOCATION_ID))
    .where(PLACE.ID.eq(1))
    .fetchInto(NearByPlace.class);

}
```

Comment: I can't see where you're trying to use Record7.  It looks like you're trying to load the result into a List of NearByPlace.  as long the object is able to construct it you should be fine.  You can see examples here:  https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.10/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos.  

You can also just do a .fetch() get a list of Record7 and manually construct the list as you see fit.  If that makes sense?

Comment: yes, i want to use Record7 along with .fetch(), any idea of how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to work with jOOQ's native `RecordX` types, simply invoke `fetch()` rather than `fetchInto(Class)`.

in this case, that should yield an `org.jooq.Result<Record7<...>>`

***UPDATE***

updated sample code as requested.

*(note: this example assumes what the type parameters for `Record7` should be based on the names of columns and what i think they mean. if i've guessed wrong, compilation will fail, but this should be a straightforward problem to fix.)*

```
        final org.joog.Result<Record7<String,String,Double,Double,String,String,String>> result = db().select(
                    PLACE.NAME.as("placeName"),
                    PLACE.TYPE.as("placeType"),
                    PLACE.LAT.as("lat"),
                    PLACE.LON.as("lon"),
                    EVENT.NAME.as("eventName"),
                    DSL.field("earth_distance(ll_to_earth(" + wrapper.lat() + "," + wrapper.lon() + "),ll_to_earth(place.lat, place.lon))* 0.000621371192").as("distanceToReach"),
                    DSL.field(EVENT.TYPE).as("eventType"))
                .from(PLACE)
                    .leftJoin(EVENT)
                        .on(PLACE.ID.eq(EVENT.LOCATION_ID))
                .where(PLACE.ID.eq(1))
                .fetch();

        return result;
```

Comment: could you please edit the sample above to reflect your thoughts ?